# FileSystem Implementation, Recursively listing files

Tags: java, recursion

I'm working on implementing the `ls` method in my program. I need to create a recursive method that will walk through my `FileSystem`.

Here is my `FileSystem` implementation right now:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FileSystem {
private Directory root;
private Directory wDir;
private ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();

// Constructor
public FileSystem() {

}

// Constructor with parameters
public FileSystem(Directory root) {
    this.root = root;
    wDir = root;
    files.add(root);
}

// Returns the FileSystem's files
public ArrayList<File> getFiles() {
    return files;
}

// Returns the working directory
public Directory getWDir() {
    return wDir;
}

// Sets the working directory
public void setWDir(Directory d) {
    wDir = d;
}

// Returns the root file. This will always be / in our program
public File getRoot() {
    return root;
}

public File getFile(File f, String name) {
    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        for (File c : ((Directory) f).getChildren()) {
            if (c.getName().equals(name))
                return c;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

// Currently only used in cat method, getFile is better
File findFile(File f, String name) {
    if (f.getName().equals(name))
        return f;
    File file = null;
    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        for (File c : ((Directory) f).getChildren()) {
            file = findFile(c, name);
            if (file != null)
                break;
        }
    }
    return file;
}

// Returns true if file is found
boolean isFile(String name) {
    File file = null;
    file = getFile(wDir, name);
    if (file != null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Creates Directory
public void mkdir(String path) {
    files.add(new Directory(path));

    int size = files.size();

    // Sets the parent
    files.get(size - 1).setParent(wDir);
    // Sets the child
    wDir.addChild(files.get(size - 1));
}

// Changes working directory
public void cd(String s) {
    if (s.equals("..")) {
        if (wDir != root) {
            wDir = wDir.getParent();
        }
    } else if (s.equals("/")) {
        wDir = root;
    } else {
        wDir = (Directory) getFile(wDir, s);
    }

}

// Provides absolute filename
public void pwd() {
    if (wDir == root) {
        System.out.println("/");
    } else {
        System.out.println(wDir.getPath());
    }
}

// Lists children of current working directory
public void ls() {
    ArrayList<File> children = wDir.getChildren();
    if (children != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
            String childName = children.get(i).getName();
            System.out.print(childName + " ");
        }
    }
}

// Lists children of file(s) inputted by user
public void ls(File f) {
    String name = f.getName();
    if (f instanceof TextFile) {
        System.out.println(f.getPath());
    } else {
        ArrayList<File> children = ((Directory) f).getChildren();
        if (children != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
                String childName = children.get(i).getName();
                System.out.print(childName + " ");
            }
        }
    }

}

// Creates a TextFile or edit's TextFile's content if already exists in the
// tree
public void edit(String name, String content) {
    files.add(new TextFile(name, content));

    // Setting TextFile parent
    files.get(files.size() - 1).setParent(wDir);
    // Setting Parent's child
    wDir.addChild(files.get(files.size() - 1));

}

// Prints the content of TextFile
public void cat(String name) {
    File f = findFile(root, name);
    System.out.println(((TextFile) f).getContent());
}

}
```

As an example of what it needs to do, let's say I have a tree like this:

```
        /
       / \
      a   b
     /     \
    x       c
   /         \
  y            d
```

If the user were to enter: `ls -r a`, my main class would convert that String value using the `getFile` method, and I would enter that into my recursive function. It would then make use of either `ls()` or `ls(File f)`, and my main program would output something like this:

```
a:
x

a/x:
y

a/x/y:
```

How should I go about creating this method?

Also I should note that I have a `Main` class, a `File` class, and a `TextFile` and `Directory` class that inherit `File`.

Any other information that is needed just let me know and I will update this post with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
public void ls(File f) {
    System.out.println(f); //or whatever is needed to print the filename
    if(f instanceof Directory) {
        List<File> fileList = ((Directory)f).getFiles();

        //with Java 8
        fileList.forEach(subFile -> System.out.println(subFile));
        fileList.forEach(subFile -> ls(subFile));

        //without Java 8
        for(File subFile : fileList) {
            System.out.println(subFile);
        }
        for(File subFile : fileList) {
            ls(subFile);
        }


        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Basically the first loop is printing all the files in the current directory and the second loop is doing that for all the subdirectories. If the File is not a Directory only it's name is printed. Here I'm assuming that your Directory class has a getFiles() method that returns a List of all Files in the Directory

Comment: Awesome, that worked. I tweaked it a bit and named it `recLS(File f, String location)` Then right at the start I `System.out.println(location + ":");` followed by `ls(f)`; And in the first loop instead of printing the `subFile`, I just did `location += "/" + c.getName();`